# how to generate excel file for a windows application using C# .net and a web application using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, export-to-excel

How to generate Excel file in the following 2 scenarios:

1. For a Windows application using C# or VB .NET
2. For a Web application using C# or VB ASP.NET

BUT without creating a local copy of the file. I want the Excel file to be generated in memory and open the file when generated. In case of the Web application I want it to show the download prompt before opening the generated Excel file.

An example would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear 2012 for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) could do this.  As far as a web application goes, take a look at any of the [Excel Reporting Samples](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx), which all dynamically generate a workbook file, starting either from scratch or from an existing template workbook file.  In either case, a "local copy" of the workbook is not generated on disk; instead, a file is saved directly to `Response.OutputStream`, which would prompt the end-user to download the workbook file.

As far as a windows application goes, SpreadsheetGear 2012 for .NET can read/write workbook files from disk/byte array/stream as well as, if desired, provide a rich interactive spreadsheet UI via the WorkbookView and FormulaBar controls for Windows Forms and WPF.  You might take a look at the following page for more information on these controls:
http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx

*Disclaimer: I work for SpreadsheetGear.*

Comment: Thanks @TimAndersen , I am looking to write code to generate excel file and send it to the client to download it. As an alternative, I am also looking for free APIs or open source APIs as well. This is because my requirement is not advanced, it merely generating excel file and password protected the file.